# Change Windows 7 Device Manager icons

Tags: windows-7, icons, device-manager

I'm looking for an easy way to manually change my Windows 7 Device Manager device icons. I've tried allowing Windows to manually download hi-res icons, but it seems to only update them when and if it feels like it, so only two of the ~20 have been updated with the proper icons.

I've tried searching around on Google but haven't found anything that really looks reliable that I can do quickly. I already have most of the icons I want to use downloaded, it's just a matter of getting them replaced.

Comment: Do you mean in "Devices and Printers" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the resource editor mentioned by jason404 (or any other if suitable) try modifying **setupapi.dll** (from the *system32* folder). Be aware of *windows file protection*.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this on executables and .dll libraries, using [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm), but I guess that it would not work on x64 drivers as it it would break the digital signing.

Why would you want to do this anyway?  It seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: Just in there a lot using a scanner and connecting/disconnecting some hardware. It just bugs me to know that I have the right icons and can't put them in there. A few of them used to work fine but no longer do.

Comment: Somebody is bored, ;-)